# Platonian geometry illustrated

Tags: reference-request, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I recently found out that a lot of Plato's work can be drawn geometrically. See the Cerritos College YouTube video ["Platos Divided Line"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKPCzRdzsWA) with the description

> Cerritos College Professor Rodney Swearengen talks about "The Mundane Geometry that Constitutes the Analogy of Plato's Divided Line and The Relevance of The Socratic Philosophy of Science Embodied Therein".

Are there any books, papers detailing this kind of work that you know of? I don't mind older sources.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "a lot of Plato's work can be drawn geometrically"??? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You can find a complete treatment of [Plato's Philosophy of Mathematics](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Plato_s_Philosophy_of_Mathematics/x0UZAQAAIAAJ) but the statement: "The Mundane Geometry that Constitutes the Analogy of Plato's Divided Line and The Relevance of The Socratic Philosophy of Science Embodied Therein" sound quite cryptic.

Comment: See also [Platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid#History) and see the [Timaeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timaeus_(dialogue)).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Did you get a chance to watch the video? He plots, using a ruler and compass the divided line from section 509d of the Republic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Correction, the divided line from section 509d-511 of the Republic. Perhaps not ALL Plato's work is plottable. Also have you heard of ["Prof. Scott A. Olsen"] http://foundationfortheosophicalstudies.co.uk/avada_portfolio/scott-a-olsen , who divided the divided line using phi ratios?